# Setting height of an element

Tags: html, css

I need to set height  of an element to adjust to the height of display.
I have tried several things however nothing seems to work

Please. see the css at the end, I have tried to adjust it per answer but still no help. I still have very tiny height. tried safarich, chrome

```
<div id='viewer'></div>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </div>
```

I have tried

```
height=device-height
height:100vh;
height 100%;
```

My css

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#viewer {
  height: 100%;        
  margin: 0 auto;     
  background: yellow; 
}
```

Comment: `width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;` does not belong in a `style` tag, those go in a `meta` tag

Comment: Can you please share the CSS file and the HTML code where you are mounting this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your `<head>` section

Then, the first div in your `<body>` must be the 'viewer'. Use this css

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#viewer {
  height: 100%;        // or 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;      // div will center if you give div a width
  background: yellow;  // test color
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="viewer">
<!-- other stuff of your page -->
</div>
</body>
```

**Update**. You did ask in the comment for more specific css, more like the css you did give in your question. This is difficult without knowing the html but as far things are common you can use the snippet below.

```css
/* full height viewport */

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
#viewer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #ffc;
}

/* nav-pills */

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* common stuff */

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* footer */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewer">
<!-- all other stuff from your body section here -->
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, can you please have a look if what I have done is correct > I tired to use your solution but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: My answer is updated with the css you did give.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following in your `CSS` file:

```css
#viewer{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

This will name the `div` with `id="viewer"` take full viewport height and width